# Dynamically Change Django Form's Fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, user-registration

In the django custom registration form I have ChoiceField see in the code below but what I want is to change the fields according to the ChoiceField options. for an example if the ChoiceField is selected as Student then I want to hide the "email field" or might add extra field. I know i can do this with JavaScript but i want to change from the form.

```
class Signup_Form(UserCreationForm):
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Signup_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # below changing on the fields of this form.
    self.fields['first_name'].label = "First Name"
    self.fields['last_name'].label = "Last Name"
    self.fields['email'].label = "Email"

 SIGNUP_USERS_TYPES = (
    ('Student', 'Student',),
    ('Admin', 'Admin',),)

 user_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices = SIGNUP_USERS_TYPES, required=True, label="Sign-up as :",)

 class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['user_type', 'first_name', 'last_name','email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template class you might have the following Javascript to achieve the desired behaviour.

Add the `email` field as a conditional field and show/hide the email field based on a value in your `user_type` field.

```
<script>
    let conditional_fields = $("#id_email");
    if ($("#id_user_type").val() === 'Student') {
        conditional_fields.parent().parent().hide();
    }
    $("#id_user_type").change(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('value') === 'Student') {
            conditional_fields.parent().parent().hide();
        } else {
            conditional_fields.parent().parent().show();
        }
    });
</script>
```